# window.location.reload(true) only works in real browsers, not VB.net WebBrowser Control

Tags: vb.net, browser, webbrowser-control, refresh, reload

I have a button on my webpage that runs some javascript code:

> alert("Will refresh now");
>
> window.location.reload(true);

It works in all the browsers we've tested it in.

But when I display that webpage inside my vb.net executable (in a WebBrowser control)... the "refresh" code is definitely run, but it just clears the screen.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: What does "when I disable that webpage inside my vb.net executable" mean? How are you disabling it?

Comment: I'm sorry... I meant "display" not "disable".

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this very simple bit of HTML/Javascript and the page refreshes just fine for me.

```
<html>
<head><title>Test</title></head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">var d = new Date(); document.write(d);</script>
<input type="button" onclick="window.location.reload();" value="Click"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And you are displaying that webpage inside a WebBrowser control... inside a vb.exe executable, right? That works 100% when in an external browser... but (for me) just "clears the screen" when I try to view that exact same webpage... from inside a WebBrowser Control. I wonder why?